# remove unwanted tags from html using python rgex

Tags: html, regex, python-3.x

i'm a beginner in python. i need a quick help for you all. here is my scenario. i am having number of html files in a folder. i need to remove some unwanted tags from those html files. can you give a best and optimized way to remove those tags in all my files(file range around 500). i user regular expression to remove those tags .

This is my sample html:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="willing pop" content="Sent for Review" />
<meta name="generator" content="Adobe RoboHelp 2015" />
<title>System Access</title>
<link rel="StyleSheet" href="..\..\..\default.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>no text found</body>
```

in the above html i want "no text found" alone.

My try but it is not working (python 3):

```
import re
with open(r"E:\python\testfiles\sample.html")as opn:
    k=opn.read()
    v=re.sub(r"<\?xml.* .*  *.>","",k,re.I|re.M)
    print(v)
```

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Use an HTML Parser. Regex is not the right tool to do it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Use lxml in python

Comment: If your question is about sanitizing HTML, there are plenty of Python packages like [html-sanitizer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html-sanitizer) out.